# Dreamweaver SPRY Custom Validation Format

Tags: validation, spry

I want a textfield to validated using dreamweaver spry option. I need the input to be in the below mentioned format

```
05632-25252525
```

The first (05632) part should contain minimum 3 no's, maximum upto 6.

The second (05632) part should contain minimum 7 no's, maximum upto 10.

how can i write a regular expression or a pattern in Spry. pls suggest

Answer (score 0):

Spry can't handle that as all one text field.

However, if you make it two textfields, then it's simplicity...just set the first one to have min 3 character, max 6 only allow numbers.  Set the second to be min7 max10 all numbers and then just combine them after the form is posted.